# How do I reformat an existing XML document with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, clone

I'm trying to update an XML document from this:

```
<Enclave id="OLD">
    <device>
        <name>MGMT</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <inform>PEM</inform>
        <outform>PEM</outform>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
</Enclave>

<Enclave id="NEW">
    
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-GooD</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <inform>PEM</inform>
        <outform>PEM</outform>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <inform>PEM</inform>
        <outform>PEM</outform>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <inform>PEM</inform>
        <outform>PEM</outform>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
</Enclave>
```

To this:

```
<Enclave id="OLD">
    <device>
        <name>MGMT</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <inform>PEM</inform>
        <outform>PEM</outform>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
</Enclave>

<Enclave id="NEW">
    
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-GooD</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <inform>PEM</inform>
        <outform>PEM</outform>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <cert>
             <inform>PEM</inform>
             <outform>PEM</outform>
             <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
             <type>WEBServer</type>
             <pwd>Password</pwd>
             <altSubject />
        </cert>
        <RequireCert>1</RequireCert>
    </device>
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <cert>
             <inform>PEM</inform>
             <outform>PEM</outform>
             <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
             <type>WEBServer</type>
             <pwd>Password</pwd>
             <altSubject />
        </cert>
        <RequireCert>1</RequireCert>
    </device>
</Enclave>
```

I've written some PowerShell commands (see below) but only have been able to get this far:

```
<Enclave id="OLD">
    <device>
        <name>MGMT</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <inform>PEM</inform>
        <outform>PEM</outform>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
</Enclave>

<Enclave id="NEW">
    
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-GooD</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <inform>PEM</inform>
        <outform>PEM</outform>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <cert>
             <inform>PEM</inform>
             <outform>PEM</outform>
             <type>WEBServer</type>
             <pwd>Password</pwd>
             <altSubject />
        </cert>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
    <device>
        <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
        <type>VoIP</type>
        <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
        <cert>
             <inform>PEM</inform>
             <outform>PEM</outform>
             <type>WEBServer</type>
             <pwd>Password</pwd>
             <altSubject />
        </cert>
        <RequireCert>1</RequireCert>
        <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
    </device>
</Enclave>
```

Here is my PowerShell code:

```
$LoadType = "NEW"
$FileName = "C:\Voip.xml"
[xml]$FileOriginal = Get-Content $FileName
$Pattern = $FileOriginal.SelectNodes("/Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"$LoadType`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]")

foreach($Pat in $Pattern) {
    $inform = $FileOriginal.SelectSingleNode("/Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"$LoadType`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]/inform")
    $inform.ParentNode.RemoveChild($inform) | Out-Null

    $outform = $FileOriginal.SelectSingleNode("/Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"$LoadType`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]/outform")
    $outform.ParentNode.RemoveChild($outform) | Out-Null

    $RequireCert = $FileOriginal.SelectSingleNode("/Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"$LoadType`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]/RequireCert")
    $RequireCert.ParentNode.RemoveChild($RequireCert) | Out-Null

    # Create cert element 
    $cert = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('cert')

    $newinform = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('inform')
    $newinform.InnerText = 'PEM'

    $newoutform = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('outform')
    $newoutform.InnerText = 'PEM'

    $type = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('type')
    $type.InnerText = 'WebServer'

    $pwd = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('pwd')
    $pwd.InnerText = 'password'

    $altSubject = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('altSubject')

    $cert.AppendChild($newinform)
    $cert.AppendChild($newoutform)
    #$cert.AppendChild($name)
    $cert.AppendChild($type)
    $cert.AppendChild($pwd)
    $cert.AppendChild($altSubject)

    # Insert cert element after 'vlan' element
    $Pat.InsertAfter( $cert, $Pat.SelectSingleNode('vlan') ) 

    $newRequireCert = $FileOriginal.CreateElement('RequireCert')
    $newRequireCert.InnerText = "1"
    $Pat.InsertAfter( $newRequireCert, $Pat.SelectSingleNode('cert') )
}

$FileOriginal.Save($FileName)
```

I couldn't get the "RequireCert" node to appear correctly with a 1 attribute in both the G-VDS-ENC001 & G-VDS-ENC002 nodes.  Also, I couldn't come up with any syntax on how to clone or copy both the G-VDS-ENC001 & G-VDS-ENC002 Node elements into the newly created Cert node.  Can anyone help me figure out what else is needed or go over my poor PowerShell code.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the existing `RequireCert` node instead of removing+recreating it:

```
# Select the node
$RequireCert = $FileOriginal.SelectSingleNode("/Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"$LoadType`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]/RequireCert")
# Set the node's text value
$RequireCert.'#Text' = 1
```

Then you can remove the `$newRequireCert` section in your current code.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So this does result in RequireCert node at the device at G-VDS-ENC001 being updated correctly but the RequireCert node at the device G-VDS-ENC002 has still not updated.

Comment: @shakex whoops! Just update the device name filter from `'G-VDS-ENC'` to `'G-VDS-ENC002'`. The `contains()` filter means both matched, and it was picking the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Cpt.Whale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68578210/9898643) you need not remove and recreate the RequireCert node.

Using dot notation you can update these nodes like this:

```
(($FileOriginal.Configuration.Enclave | Where-Object { $_.id -eq $LoadType }).device | 
  Where-Object { $_.name -like 'G-VDS-ENC*' }) | ForEach-Object { $_.RequireCert = '1' }
```